# How can I add a point label to this plot?

Tags: labeling

I am using the listlineplot function. How do I label a specific point with text?

Comment: `ListPlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 4}, Callout[{3, 9}, 9]}]`

Answer (score 1):

ListPlot[{{1, 1}, Labeled[{2, 4}, "hola"], Callout[{3, 9}, 9]}]

Comment: `ListLinePlot[{{1, 1}, Labeled[{2, 4}, "hola"], Callout[{3, 9}, 9]}, 
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic]`